# How to change the first two uppercase characters on each line to lowercase in Vim?

Tags: text, full-text-search, text-editor, vim

I have the following text:

```
HELLO TO STACKOVERFLOW
WELCOME TO STACKOVERFLOW
```

I want the text to be changed as follows:

```
heLLO TO STACKOVERFLOW
weLCOME TO STACKOVERFLOW
```

How can I do that in Vim?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Highlight a visual block for the first two colums with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>

[image]

Enter `gu` or `u` to downcase the selected text, `gU` or `U` to upcase.

[image]

Comment: or `~` to invert case. Be cautious when sending screenshots, your window is half-transparent, have special care if you have sensible data behind (here no worries)

Comment: @Benoit Yeah I will, but I don't have anything to hide :) Thanks for the edit and the `~` tip.

Comment: +1 for anyone else using VsVim in Visual Studio, the `~` trick works (`gu` and `gU` didn't work for me).

Answer (score 9):

While @Jin provided a good answer for interactive use, here's a way to do it in scripting:

to run to every line of the buffer:

```
:%normal 0gu2l
```

or you can specify a line range where to apply the command. This will apply for lines 4 and 5:

```
:4,5normal 0gu2l
```

Comment: +1, you can also specify the columns that you want to work with. `:%normal 15|gu3l` will downcase columns 15 to 17 for all rows.

Answer (score 5):

In normal mode:

- if `startofline` is set (`:verb set sol?` will tell you) you can use: `lgu`<kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>`G`.
  Detail :

  - `l` goes to next character
  - `gu` is the `make lowercase` operator, expecting a motion
  - `CTRL-V` specifies that the motion is blockwise
  - `G` goes to first column in last line.
- if `startofline` is not set, then `gu`<kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>`Gl.` (`l` goes to next character, and `.` repeats the same command).

For changing to uppercase change `gu` with `gU`, for switching case ensure that `tildeop` is set and use `~` instead.

Comment: Nice explanation of `'startofline'` and use of `'tildeop'`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to answers given by @Benoit, @Jin and  @progo:

```
:%s/^../\L&\E/
```

see `:help sub-replace-special`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the substitution

```
:%s/.*\%3c/\L&
```

which takes advantage of the `\%c` search pattern atom matching the
character at a specific column on a line. Using that atom you can
easily adjust the pattern to match any particular number of leading characters
on a line.

Comment: See `:h s/\L` for this and other substitution special characters.