# Regex to replace first lowercase character in a line into uppercase

Tags: regex, text, replace, editor

I have a very large file containing thousands of sentences. In all of them, the first word of each sentence begins with lowercase, but I need them to begin with uppercase.

I looked through the site trying to find a regex to do this but I was unable to. I learned a lot about regex in the process, which is always a plus for my job, but I was unable to find specifically what I am looking for.

I tried to find a way of compiling the code from several answers, including the following:

- [Convert first lowercase to uppercase and uppercase to lowercase (regex?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770261/convert-first-lowercase-to-uppercase-and-uppercase-to-lowercase-regex)
- [how to change first two uppercase character to lowercase character on each line in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657537/how-to-change-first-two-uppercase-character-to-lowercase-character-on-each-line)
- [Regex, two uppercase characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619955/regex-two-uppercase-characters-in-a-string)
- [Convert a char to upper case using regular expressions (EditPad Pro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159343/convert-a-char-to-upper-case-using-regular-expressions-editpad-pro/1159389#1159389)

But for different reasons none of them served my purpose.

I am working with a translation-specific application which accepts regex.

Do you think this is possible at all? It would save me hours of tedious work.

Comment: Match `^[^a-z]*[a-z]` and replace with `\U$0`? (you'll need an editor that supports `\U`)

Comment: If your editor doesn't support it, it's quite easy to write a script (eg. in Python) to achieve what you want.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it looks like it does not support \U :/. Also, when using the ^[^a-z]*[a-z] regex I get every single lowercase character, not only the first lowercase character in the first word of each line. I don't know if my editor is somehow limited.

Comment: If your editor matches *all* lowercase characters with that pattern, your editor's regex engine is probably broken. The pattern I posted worked fine for me. It would greatly help if you posted an example input and expected output

Comment: Expected input: regex can make my job easier
Expected output: Regex can make my job easier

Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this regex to search for the first letters of sentences:

`(?<=[\.!?]\s)([a-z])`

It matches a lowercase letter `[a-z]`, following the end of a previous sentence (which might end with one of the following: `[\.!?]`) and a space character `\s`.

Then make a substitution with `\U$1`.

It doesn't work only for the very first sentence. I intentionally kept the regex simple, because it's easy to capitalize the very first letter manually.

**Working example**: https://regex101.com/r/hqwK26/1

**UPD:** If your software doesn't support `\U`, you might want to copy your text to Notepad++ and make a replacement there. The `\U` is fully supported, just checked.

**UPD2:** According to the comments, the task is slightly different, and just the first letters of each line should be capitalized.

There is a simple regex for that: `^([a-z])`, with the same substitution pattern.

Here is a **working example**: https://regex101.com/r/hqwK26/2

Comment: Thanks Ildar, it looks like this is pretty close to what I need. But all sentences begin with the word lowercase and I need each first word to be uppercased, and not the ones after the end of a previous sentence. Do you think it's possible?
Right, my software does not support \U. I would need to find an alternative solution.

Comment: @CanoEE Can you give an example? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes, it would be as follows:

Expected input: regex can make my job easier 
Expected output: Regex can make my job easier

It's just a list of sentences starting with lowercase and ending with period. I just need to change the first letter of the first word of each sentence (regex in the example) from lowercase into uppercase (Regex would be the expected output.

Thanks again!

Comment: @CanoEE Please check the example here: https://regex101.com/r/hqwK26/2 . If it is what you need, I'll go ahead and update the answer.

Comment: Awesome! It is exactly that, thanks a million! My software does not allow me the use of \u, I guess there is no other way to do it without copying to Notepad, am I right?
Really thankful for your help!!!

Comment: @CanoEE Yes, you should just copy/paste to Notepad++ or something else. I updated the answer, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: \U is printing as it is in my code. I am substituting `\U$1`. and my expression is `([\.!?])(\s*)([a-z])`. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Taking Ildar's answer and combining both of his patterns should work with no compromises.
`(?<=[\.!?]\s)([a-z])|^([a-z])`
This is basically saying, if first pattern OR second pattern. But because you're now technically extracting 2 groups instead of one, you'll have to refer to group 2 as `$2`. Which should be fine because only one of the patterns should be matched.
So your substitution pattern would then be as follows...
`\U$1$2`

Here's a working example, again based on Ildar's answer...
https://regex101.com/r/hqwK26/13

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consider posting your example in the space provided here instead of an external link.